# How to do natural sort with scientific numbers?

Tags: python

I have problem sorting list with scientific numbers.

Here is an example,

```
my_list = ['Time:  1.00000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.00000E+02 h', 'Time:  1.50000E+01 h']
```

I want the list order to be more natural like this.

```
sorted_list = ['Time:  1.00000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.50000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.00000E+02 h']
```

How can I do that?

So far, I tried the package `natsort` and `natsorted(my_list)` did not return the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract and convert the numbers to actual `float` values in your `key` function, and it should work just fine:

```
my_list = ['Time:  1.00000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.00000E+02 h', 'Time:  1.50000E+01 h']

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: float(x.split()[1]))

print(my_list)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7cyPiezuETBViFaPSQzN9VKQcFQzwAEXLUNDBUy1HUUMMWN0MRNkdTHcnFBzdQrzi8q0chOrbTNScxNSklUqLBSSMvJTyzRqNArLsjJLNHQjDaM1dTk4iooyswr0YBq0/z/HwA)

which outputs:

```
['Time:  1.00000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.50000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.00000E+02 h']
```

If you want to leave the original `list` unchanged, do this instead of calling `.sort` on `my_list`:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: float(x.split()[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\d\.\d+E\+\d+")
my_list = ['Time:  1.00000E+01 h', 'Time:  1.00000E+02 h', 'Time:  1.50000E+01 h']
sorted(my_list, key=lambda m: float(pattern.findall(m)[0]))
```

Comment: Won't work if scientific number starts with another digit